# $or search on virtual populate mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to create a search function for one of my schemas. This schema has 4 virtual populate maps that I would also like to search on. I can use match on my virtual populates but that will limit all of my results unless those are met.

```js
multiSchema: {

     plat: String,
     k_1: String,
     K_2: String
}

multiSchema.virtual({
     ref: 'singles',
     localField: 'k_1',
     foreignField: 'singles_special_id',
     justOne: true
})

multiSchema.virtual({
     ref: 'singles',
     localField: 'k_2',
     foreignField: 'singles_special_id',
     justOne: true
})

singleSchema: {
    single_special_id,
    n: String
    //
    **otherfields**
    ////
}

multi.find({
    $or: [{
        plat: {
          $regex: input,
          $options: 'i'
        }
      },
      {
        k_1: {
          $regex: input,
          $options: 'i'
        }
      },
      {
        k_2: {
          $regex: input,
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }
    ]
  }).lean()
  .populate({
    path: 'k_p_1',
    match: {
      $or: [{
        n: {
          $regex: input,
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }]
    }
  })
  .populate({
    path: 'k_p_2',
    match: {
      $or: [{
        n: {
          $regex: input,
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }]
    }
  })
  .populate({
    path: 'h_p_1',
    match: {
      $or: [{
        n: {
          $regex: input,
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }]
    }
  })
  .populate({
    path: 'h_p_2',
    match: {
      $or: [{
        n: {
          $regex: input,
          $options: 'i'
        }
      }]
    }
  })
  .exec()
```

Example Data:

```
multi: {
   plat: "foo"
   k_1: "hello",
   k_2: "world"
}

single: {
   singles_special_id: "hello"
   n: "bar"
}
```

If I try and search for bar, it doesn't return any multi schemas because the population probably happens after the multi schema values are searched.

Comment: Without the schemas, it is hard to know what could be the issue. Do the populates work without matching?

Comment: @JasonCust I added some schemas that are basically what I have. A multi schema is simply an object with multiple single schema objects. So I want to search on these K_1 and K_fields and also search the information within the single schema object that is paired on populate. my populates only return one single schema that pairs.

Comment: @JasonCust I also added a test set of data so I hope that clarifies things a little better.